# write id3v2 tags to mp3 file using php?

Tags: php, mp3

I need to write ID3v2 tags to mp3 files using php , any solutions ?

could not get how to use [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2462-PHP-Read-and-write-the-ID3Tag-of-MP3-files.html)

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the example on the website? http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/10144.html

Comment: Could not get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*getid3* is another Module that can write (and of course read) id3v2 Tags using PHP.

Get it on Sourceforge: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/source/write.id3v2.phps

Comment: Are you sure it's bugs and not your usage of the class? :) I've successfully used this library some time ago to display ID3 data, so I assume writing would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Zend PHP Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/)'s [Zend_Media_Id3v2 Class](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ID3v2).

Comment: Something without need to install extra software ?